# Python Mock getting address instead return_value

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, return-value

I am trying to sub out a call to check a users full name. I have written the below method using mock to do this.

```py
def test_UserDisplayName(self):
    appModel = Mock()
    eval = appModel.eval.return_value
    eval.userDisplayName.return_value = 'JohnDoe'
    self._SummaryModel.AppModel = appModel
    actual = self._SummaryModel.UserDisplayName()
    self.assertEqual(actual, 'JohnDoe')
```

This is the method it is calling.

```
def UserDisplayName(self):
    return self.AppModel().eval().userDisplayName()
```

If I attached debugger to the above line and the run it in the shell it works

```py
[PAUSED] >>> self.AppModel().eval().userDisplayName()
'JohnDoe'
[PAUSED] >>>
```

But when the run the test case for it fails as it I am getting the address back rather than the value.

```py
   ======================================================================
   FAIL: test_UserDisplayName (unittests.model.SummaryModelTest)
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/unittests/summary_model.py", line 112, in test_UserDisplayName
       self.assertEqual(actual, 'JohnDoe')
   AssertionError: <Mock name='mock.userDisplayName()' id='233406864'> != 'JohnDoe'

   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Ran 1 test in 0.010s

   FAILED:  (failures=1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your code calls `AppModel` as well, so you need to adjust the other references for that:

```
eval = appModel.return_value.eval.return_value
```

Demo:

```
>>> from unittest.mock import Mock
>>> appModel = Mock()
>>> eval = appModel.return_value.eval.return_value
>>> eval.userDisplayName.return_value = 'JohnDoe'
>>> appModel().eval().userDisplayName()
'JohnDoe'
```

However, your `<Mock name='mock.userDisplayName()' id='233406864'>` object shows a name of `mock.userDisplayName()` which suggests that the return value was produced by using `self.AppModel.userDisplayName()` *directly* instead.

Comment: Added the above line but still it doesn't work and when I attach the debug point it doesn't work either. `code` [PAUSED] >>> self.AppModel().eval().userDisplayName()
<Mock name='mock.eval().userDisplayName()' id='232555600'>
[PAUSED] >>>

Comment: @Eamonn: Test each individual step of that expression and see if the *same mock* is returned as what your test sets up. So does `self.AppModel()` return `appModel.return_value`?

Comment: I am putting `dir()` on each step so I started on `self.AppModel()` I can see `'eval'` and then when I do a `dir()` on `self.AppModel().eval()` I can see userDisplayName.

Comment: @Eamonn: looking at your `AssertionError` I don't see the expected `mock().eval().userDisplayName()` name for the mock. Are you certain about how `UserDisplayName` is implemented?