# Mocking elasticsearch-py calls

Tags: python, unit-testing, elasticsearch, mocking

I'm writing a CLI to interact with elasticsearch using the elasticsearch-py library. I'm trying to mock elasticsearch-py functions in order to test my functions without calling my real cluster.

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44984887/python-mock-what-is-return-value-in-the-following) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431084/python-mock-getting-address-instead-return-value) but I still don't understand.

**main.py**

`Escli` inherits from cliff's `App` [class](https://github.com/openstack/cliff/blob/master/cliff/app.py)

```
class Escli(App):
    _es = elasticsearch5.Elasticsearch()
```

**settings.py**

```
from escli.main import Escli

class Settings:
    def get(self, sections):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class ClusterSettings(Settings):

    def get(self, setting, persistency='transient'):
        settings = Escli._es.cluster\
                    .get_settings(include_defaults=True, flat_settings=True)\
                    .get(persistency)\
                    .get(setting)

        return settings
```

**settings_test.py**

```
import escli.settings


class TestClusterSettings(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.patcher = patch('elasticsearch5.Elasticsearch')
        self.MockClass = self.patcher.start()

    def test_get(self):
        # Note this is an empty dict to show my point
        # it will contain childs dict to allow my .get(persistency).get(setting)
        self.MockClass.return_value.cluster.get_settings.return_value = {}

        cluster_settings = escli.settings.ClusterSettings()
        ret = cluster_settings.get('cluster.routing.allocation.node_concurrent_recoveries', persistency='transient')
        # ret should contain a subset of my dict defined above
```

I want to have `Escli._es.cluster.get_settings()` to return what I want (a `dict` object) in order to not make the real HTTP call, but it keeps doing it.

**What I know:**

- In order to mock an instance method I have to do something like
  `MagicMockObject.return_value.InstanceMethodName.return_value = ...`
- I cannot patch `Escli._es.cluster.get_settings` because Python tries to import `Escli` as module, which cannot work. So I'm patching the whole lib.

I desperately tried to put some `return_value` everywhere but I cannot understand why I can't mock that thing properly.

Comment: You have to mock with respect to where you are testing. Since you are testing the `settings.py` module, then you need to reference your mocking accordingly. So, in your `setUp`, your `patch` path should be something like: `patch('escli.settings.Escli')`. So now when you call the `settings` code explicitly like you are in your tests, you are now properly mocking in the right place.

Comment: Furthermore, you might want spec your `Mock` with the Elasticsearch class in order to validate you are using the valid attributes available in the class. So, you might want to do the following: `patch('escli.settings.Escli', Mock(Elasticsearch))`

Comment: Just to put it out there, `pytest` does provide a plugin you can use for elasticsearch if you are interested in other options as well: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-elasticsearch/

Comment: You made my day ! I will dig to understand that `Mock()` thing. Would you consider making an answer as you solved the case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be mocking with respect to where you are testing. Based on the example provided, this means that the `Escli` class you are using in the `settings.py` module needs to be mocked with respect to `settings.py`. So, more practically, your `patch` call would look like this inside `setUp` instead:

```
self.patcher = patch('escli.settings.Escli')
```

With this, you are now mocking what you want in the right place based on how your tests are running.

Furthermore, to add more robustness to your testing, you might want to consider speccing for the `Elasticsearch` instance you are creating in order to validate that you are in fact calling valid methods that correlate to `Elasticsearch`. With that in mind, you can do something like this, instead:

```
self.patcher = patch('escli.settings.Escli', Mock(Elasticsearch))
```

To read a bit more about what exactly is meant by `spec`, check the [patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) section in the documentation.

As a final note, if you are interested in exploring the great world of [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/), there is a [pytest-elasticsearch](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-elasticsearch/) plugin created to assist with this.